# Jquery - get disabled elements

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use Jquery to iterate through an array of textboxes where i only want  textboxes that are 'enabled'.
can someone give me the best way to do this? Would i use the filter method ?

(ie:)

```
var arrayOfTextBoxes = $("[id$='" + textBoxId + "']");

var enabledTextBoxes = $(arrayOfTextBoxes).????
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`:enabled` selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/enabled).

```
//this will find the checkbox if it is enabled
$("#"+textBoxId+":enabled")
```

Comment: I don't think that IE8 and below will perform the above correctly. I believe that this :enabled pseudo-class with respect to Internet Explorer has basic support only for IE9 and above...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(arrayOfTextBoxes).filter(':enabled')
```

or

```
$("[id$='" + textBoxId + "']:enabled")
```

in the first place.

Comment: ohh nice, i've got a couple of ways to do this.
Thanks!!